# How can i open/serve a file locate on another computer in Go?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I work on an web application written in Go and React. I am deploying that app on Google Cloud Platform, for which I chose the Compute Engine service.

I created 3 instances: an instance for running the Go part of the application, an other for the database server and the last for the React part. The OS of the three instances is Ubuntu 18.04.

I want my Go program to retrieve data from my database (that part works well) and serve them to the client (React) using websocket.

When I test my app locally, everything runs as expected but it's because html/css/js files are on the same computer that my Go files. But on GCE they are on two differents VMs. Actually this is how I serve a html file with Go:

```
indexFile, err := os.Open("views/index.html")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
index, err := ioutil.ReadAll(indexFile)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(index))
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

Does someone knows how I can make my app work with Go code on a VM and html/css/js on an other ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Deploy the assets to the machine that needs them.

Comment: Hi @ThunderCat :) There is no other way to do it with the back and the front of my app stored on two separate machines ??

Comment: How did the Go templates get into some other VM? They should all be on the same VM as your Go program.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to store the application's assets on the machine that runs the application?

Comment: There are literally an infinite number of ways to serve a file from one computer to another. In fact, that's essentially the only thing... the _only thing_ the Internet does. So asking how it can be done is a bit like asking "Explain how everything on the Internet works."

Comment: You could also use a forward proxy, that serves (depending on the url) the assets from the react instance and the websocket from the go app.
There are many possibilities. You should consider your options, try one out, and come back if you still have problems with a specific solution.

Comment: Your architecture of 3 separate servers with different roles seems like a bad idea.  But as everyone else has pointed out this question has too many answers

Comment: I don't uderstand. Why you have 2 different instance for React and Go? It seems you want to serve the React application with your Go application. If so, they should be on the same instance.